# 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, angular, web-services

I am using angular for client and Java as backend service facing the below issue. I went through all available online resources but no luck any help will be appreciated.
**"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/demo/customer' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

**Controller code:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class CustomerController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @GetMapping("/customer")
    public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        
        return customerService.get();
        
    }
    
}
```

**Configuration Code:**

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public CORSFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        ((UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource) source).registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CORSFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: When CORS is enabled in Spring, all endpoint access errors appear as CORS errors by default in the client because when an error happens (authentication or otherwise) the header is not set.
Please enable full server logging, and paste the relevant log. You can use `logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE` for it in your Spring properties file. There you will be able to see if it's due to a missing permission, wrong URL, or otherwise.

Comment: disable default config add in .property file spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration

Comment: You should check the `Network` tab in your broswer and check if this header is present in the response. `5xx` (Internal Server Error) at back-end will be thrown as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in chrome (have not tried with other browsers) browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    String localURI = "http://localhost:4200";

    List<String> allowedOrigins = List.of(localURI);
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(java.util.List.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
    // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
    // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(java.util.List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```